# How long do surges last?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

Sometimes people in the Barracks get a surge in a couple of their stats. How long do these surges last? What about if I don't use that person to fight with?

Comment: As far as I know surges last one battle whether you bring the unit or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stat boosts, from either tonics or surges, disappear after one battle, whether the character with those boosts participates in that battle or not.